# Screensavers for 200 tablets - accessed centrally from one computer - Is this possible?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, google, photos, google-photos

Hi I'm involved in a project to deploy 200 tablets. All devices will be on different networks in various locations around Australia.

I would like all devices to access the one set of screen savers and be able to update them all on demand. Is there an easy way to do this?

Currently I am thinking of logging into all devices from one gmail account and assigning the screensavers to google photos, and changing the photos from this one location.

I understand that google may not allow to 200 devices to sign into from one account.

Does anybody have any better ideas?  Many thanks, Anthony

Comment: Look at [Android for Work/Enterprise](https://www.android.com/enterprise/). While for developers, [the guide document](https://developer.android.com/work/guide) does cover the supported scenarios.

Comment: there are 3rd party MDM solutions [example](https://mdm.manageengine.com/free-trial.html)